# Caused by: org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code

Tags: spring, internationalization

Attempting to get Spring internationalization working. I have used classpath:messages basename, created .properties files for languages. They are being corectly copied to web-inf folder and the codes exist within properties file ...

Here is the ide showing everything, please help me. I have copied the set up from another project I have done that works fine. I have tried creating a load of different message files, but its not picking anything up ... pic shows web.xml, spring-servlet.xml, and directory structure.

[image: This shows everything, I can't see what I am missing]

**Edit**
If I add the bean definition to applicationContext instead of spring-servlet it works .. ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll go for my try:

If the file is located under the `WEB-INF/classes` directory, try :

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/classes/messages" />
</bean>
```

And the name of the file should be either :

- messages.properties
- messages_en.properties
- messages_en_GB.properties

**Edit** - Final try !

What about this way of writing the configuration, I smell sthg here after your last comment:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: already tried that, but will try again. And yes tried those properties file (in screenshot), even though messages_en.properties works in my other project.

Comment: Try to keep only one of them in your directory ?

Comment: I have been looking at this for far too long. Its going to somethign so small and annoying

Comment: wait so what was the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Keep your message property files outside the classpath(WEB-INF/classes) and define the bean as below

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages"/>
<property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/>
```

As per the doc ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource provides you benefit of changing the messages on the fly which spring fetches through the cachSeconds. This class differs from ResourceBundleMessageSource only in specifying the resource location.

Comment: Yes thats why you need to keep properties files outside the classpath as I have mentioned.\

Comment: I don't think that is correct. My other projects, and the other replies here all work fine. But I will try, and I will be eternally grateful if correct

Answer (score 0):

All the configurartion details all correct but do one thing which ever property files are configured in child configuration file it means your spring-servlet.xml configure all the properties into applicationContext.xml it means parent configuration file maximum it will works. try it and remove the configuration of property details in spring-servlet.xml...........

Answer (score -1):

Though to many this sounds foolish, but the mistake my code had that we had written our own MessageSource. Which was calling Spring's MessageSource.

But in the code it was like (MessageSource(MessageSource)). Hence we were doing look up over look up.

Removed the extra call, and its working now.